# ga4 measurement protocol new users 0

Tags: google-analytics

I have desktop app on Delphi. App send next data to https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect:

```
{
  "app_instance_id": "47DA283039DE19AA64A5382C7936AE0F",
  "events": [
    {"name": "login", "params": {
      "engagement_time_msec": "1",
      "app_version": "3.5.37",
      "client_id": "118"
    }}
  ]
}
```

Google Analytics showing Active Users and Events. But New Users is 0. Also geolocation is no set.

I find answer, that needed pass a clint_id param ("client_id": "66676792622744477"), but after that GA cause an error:

```
{
  "validationMessages": [ {
    "description": "Unable to parse Measurement Protocol JSON payload. : invalid value oneof field 'AnonymousUserIdentifier' is already set. Cannot set 'client_id' for type oneof",
    "validationCode": "VALUE_INVALID"
  } ]
}
```

Help me please, whats wrong? How can I track New users and Geo via GA4 measurement protocol?

Answer (score 0):

Try to send `user_id` information to GA4 Property: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/user-id?platform=websites

Comment: Needed to setup engagement_time_msec https://stackoverflow.com/a/71482548/7006347